# Activate custom virtual space via HTA app

Tags: function, jscript, hta

I made a HTA app that sets virtual space to custom instead of automatic, but I came across with following problem, when I run the function it says that computername is not defined, however if you are running it in CMD everything works just fine.

I assume in HTA you need to use some special characters for symbols like %,=, etc?

This is my function:

```
function enablevirtualspace(){
  var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var sComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMPUTERNAME%");
  var path = "wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" set AutomaticManagedPagefile=false";
  wshShell.run(path,1,false);
}
```

Comment: I believe problem is associated with this part of the code ```name="%computername%"```, Probably I have to inbound this part is some special characters, otherwise, code can't read command correctly.

Comment: I have tried that one, problem is that it gives me an error message saying 'Permission Denied'. I thought it was my bad... so this error is associated with something else rather than bad coding?

Comment: It means you don't have permission to execute the command, so try running the script with elevated privileges.

Comment: I tried running HTA app as admin via a batch file, but I still get a permission error. Is there another method I am not aware of?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was with antivirus, it was blocking execution.

Comment: Please submit your comment as an answer and I will mark your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you don't have permission to execute the command, so try running the script with elevated privileges.

By [Lankymart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692942/lankymart)